# Indiscrete topology regular and normal?

Tags: general-topology

I came across some tables in "counterexamples for topology" that contradict some of the properties I have determined in the following table I have created.It says that none of the properties on the chart I created are satisfied by the indiscrete topology. I thought the indiscrete topology was regular, normal, and separable, the chart says it is not? What is going on here? It says $4$ is for the indiscrete.

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
 & \mbox{T1} & \mbox{Hausdorff}&\mbox{Regular} & \mbox{Normal}&\mbox{Separable}\\
\hline
\mathbb{R}&Y & Y & Y&Y&Y\\
\mathbb{R}^n&Y & Y & Y&Y&Y\\
\mbox{indiscrete}&N & N & Y&Y&Y\\
\mbox{discrete}&Y & Y & Y&Y&Y\\
\mbox{Cofinite}& Y& N&N &N&Y \\
\mbox{Cocountable}&Y&N&N&N&Y\\
\mathbb{R}_l&Y &Y &Y &Y&Y\\
\mbox{line w  2 origins} &Y &N &N &N&Y\\
\mbox{ordered  square} & Y&Y &Y &Y&N \\
\mathbb{R}_k &Y &Y &N &N&Y\\
\{0,1\}^A &Y &Y &Y &Y&Y
\end{array}$$

[image]

Comment: the [indiscrete topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology#Details) is regular, normal, and separable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people, unfortunately, including Steen and Seebach, fail to recognize that the $T_k$ designations are supposed to form a hierarchy, so that $T_k$ implies $T_\ell$ whenever $k\ge\ell$. For you and me $T_3$ means *regular plus* $T_1$, and $T_4$ means *normal plus* $T_1$. For people like Steen and Seebach who follow the other convention, *regular* and *normal* are our $T_3$ and $T_4$, respectively, and $T_3$ and $T_4$ are our *regular* and *normal*, respectively. Thus, for them a regular or normal space must be $T_1$, but a $T_3$ or $T_4$ space need not be $T_1$. They also switch $T_{3½}$ and *completely regular*.

Comment: Ok thanks now I understand. You don't assume normal and regular imply $T_1$ because that's for $T_3$ and $T_4$. On the other hand the authors of this book do make that assumption which I know munkres sometimes establishes at the onset, by stating "one points sets are open". It seems to me though (at least as far as I have made it through munkres) that munkres does not even mention $T_3$ or $T_4$.

Comment: @DanielSchmidt: You’re welcome. Munkres is a very good expositor, and I don’t know of any book at that level that is clearly better than his, but he did make some decisions that I find rather odd, to say the least.

Comment: In Munkres 2nd edition paragraph 31, page 205, the paragraph in which he defines regular and normal starts with the sentence *Suppose that one-point sets are closed in $X$. Then $X$ is said to be regular...* So $T_1$ is included somewhat sneakily. @DanielSchmidt